# Convert a single element list to a string

Tags: string, list, ansible

I have a list with just one value

```yaml
"list": [
            "abcdef0000001"
        ]
```

which I need to convert to a string, to be like:

```yaml
"var": "abcdef0000001"
```

Is there an easy way to do it? I couldn't find it.

I tried converting with `| string` but that didn't help.

Comment: `list.0`, `list[0]` or `list | first`, what you like best.

Comment: Yes, like I thought - a very simple solution, but still if you don't know it... Thank you both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly assign "var" = list[0]

Hope this should work for you

Comment: That's wrong. You can't assign variable by using `=`.